# Injecting EntityManager results in NullPointerException in TomEE?

Tags: java, ejb, openejb

Here's my MovieBean.java:

```
@Stateless
public class MovieBean {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MovieBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Movie m");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

My `MoviesServlet` uses this MovieBean like this:

```
@WebServlet("/MoviesServlet")
public class MoviesServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private MovieBean mb;

private List<Movie> getMovies() {
    return mb.getAllMovies();
}
```

And in my `doGet` method I use the `getMovies` method to get a list of all movies. However, I get the following exceptions:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:363)
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)
bg.cinemate.beans.MovieBean$LocalBeanProxy.getAllMovies(bg/cinemate/beans/MovieBean.java)
bg.cinemate.servlets.MoviesServlet.getMovies(MoviesServlet.java:27)
bg.cinemate.servlets.MoviesServlet.doGet(MoviesServlet.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

java.lang.NullPointerException
bg.cinemate.beans.MovieBean.getAllMovies(MovieBean.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.invoke(CdiInterceptor.java:126)
org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.access$000(CdiInterceptor.java:42)
org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor$1.call(CdiInterceptor.java:63)
org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiInterceptor.aroundInvoke(CdiInterceptor.java:69)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:176)
org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:95)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:181)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:163)
org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:138)
org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:239)
org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:191)
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:246)
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:241)
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:83)
org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:279)
bg.cinemate.beans.MovieBean$LocalBeanProxy.getAllMovies(bg/cinemate/beans/MovieBean.java)
bg.cinemate.servlets.MoviesServlet.getMovies(MoviesServlet.java:27)
bg.cinemate.servlets.MoviesServlet.doGet(MoviesServlet.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

My `persistance.xml` file is configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
            <persistence-unit name="cinema" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                    <properties>
                            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinema" />
                            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
                            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
                            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
                            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
                    </properties>

            </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

I tried changing it (tried with the one shown [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/)) but it does not even start the server (says the time limit has exceeded, even after I tried changing it to 200 seconds).
I use Java7, OpenEJB and TomEE.

**EDIT 1:**
I changed my `persistence.xml` to this:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
      <persistence-unit transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" name="cinema">
        <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Connector/Default JDBC Database</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Connector/Default Unmanaged JDBC Database</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>bg.cinemate.beans.MovieBean</class>

        <properties>
          <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Tried `@PersistenceContext(unitName="cinema")` and the server started, but it gives me the same exceptions.

Comment: I would leave the header of persistence.xml at version 2.0 and not revert to 1.0

Comment: Again, a mechanical error, but the result when using version 2.0 is the same two exceptions.

Comment: I have edited my answer again. I think you may need to provide the provider element to your config.

Answer (score 3):

I Had exactly the same problem while using OpenJPA2 with similar structure.
The one that solved my NullPointer problem was changing `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` to `transaction-type="JTA"`. Though in this case I get this exception: `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: user lacks privilege or object not found`.

Correction:
The last exception is solved and all transactions are running perfectly after I mapped correctly the datasource from tomee to the persistence.xml

tomee.xml:

```
<Resource id="mydatabaseDS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase
    UserName myuser
    Password mypassword
    JtaManaged true
</Resource>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>mydatabaseDS</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Don't forget to add you jdbc driver lib into the {tomee}/lib dir.

Answer (score 2):

There can be several reasons to this:

1. Your class `Movie` is not an entity. In this case, post your `Movie` class code. Check if it is annotated with `@Entity`. Or define `Movie` inside your `persistence.xml`.

   I am looking at your `persistence.xml` and I am seeing `MovieBean` inside the file. This is wrong. You don't need EJB inside your file. You need to define class which is entity like `Movie`.

   Change it like this:

   ```xml
   <class>YourPackagePath.Movie</class>
   ```
2. Your EJB is not managed. Means your EJB fails to deploy properly. In this case, it will not be managed by container and annotation lookup will fail. Check if your EJB is mapped to a JNDI name. You can check this through Server GUI, Server Startup Log or 3rd party App.
3. The name of your `DataSource` is wrong.

   In this line `<jta-data-source>java:openejb/Connector/Default JDBC Database</jta-data-source>`, you don't need to prefix `java:`. Only use JNDI name of your `DataSource`. Again check if the JNDI name of your `DataSource` is correct. You can check this as mentioned in Point#2.
4. Don't use JTA and Non-JTA dataSources together. JTA is used when you don't handle transaction manually and Non-JTA is used when you need to handle transaction manually in your code. Use JTA. That should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your EJB:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="cinema")
private EntityManager em;
```

Also, your file should be called persistence.xml, not persistance.xml and needs to be under the folder META-INF.

When using a RESOURCE_LOCAL datasource, the names of your entity classes must be provided in this file.

The name of the persistence provider should also be given in this file:

```
<provider> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl </provider>
```

Edit: Ensure the PersistenceProviderImpl class is on the classpath when your code runs on the server

Comment: It is called persistence.xml, I made a typo. I tried using `unitName="cinema"`, but it gives me the same exceptions.

Comment: I have amended my answer. Is the file under the META-INF folder?

Comment: It's under Java Resources/src/META-INF, yes.

Comment: @Milan Milanov Check where it resides in your deployed EJB artifact. The META-INF folder needs to be at the root of the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project with a similar structure to yours. Here is the major difference between mine and yours

```
protected static EntityManagerFactory
 em=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cinema");
```

You might be getting the null pointer exception in your MovieBean class as you have not created the entitymanager factory. It has not been instansiated and that is why you are getting the null pointer exception. This code has not been tested in your case. It just stands out to me so I said I would say it.

EDIT:
After looking at the tomcat site via your link there is also

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "cinema", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
 private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Manually creating EMF is only mandatory if the container doesn't support `@PersistenceContext` nor EJBs, such as Tomcat. However, OP is using OpenEJB, so this answer only makes things worse as you've to change a lot more things, such as manually starting and stopping user transactions which would only introduce a lot of code boilerplate.

Comment: Generally speaking, null pointer exceptions are thrown if there is a logical error in the code. You are right though @BalusC. The reason I put down this, was to hint to that there might be reason to change a few things to work in this case. `@PersistenceContext` was not working in the case, and it was just an alternative thinking process rather than providing a solution to the problem.